# Heartbeat active/passive not working

Tags: heartbeat, centos6.2, heartbeat1

I've installed Heartbeat in two CentOS 6.2 machines which are running http service. I want these machines to be in Active/Passive state. I want only one machine to be active. Here's my `ha.cf` file:

```
logfacility     local0
ucast   eth1    192.168.0.66
#bcast eth1
keepalive 2
warntime 6
deadtime 10
auto_failback on
use_logd yes

node    web5
node    web5b
```

And here's the `haresources` file:

```
web5    IPaddr::192.168.0.60/24/eth1/192.168.0.255
```

The problem is when I start heartbeat on both servers, the IP 192.168.0.60 stays active in both servers. I want it to be active only on Web5 and if web5 goes down it'll be active in Web5b. My heartbeat version is 3.0.4.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you may have made this more difficult.  I just setup this for heartbeat active/failover.  In you haresources files, try removing the bcast address and make is like below.

```
web5 IPADDR::192.168.193.60/24/eth0 httpd
```

Your ha.cf file needs a quick edit too.  Uncomment "bcast eth1" so heartbeat will use broadcast on eth1.  Make sure httpd is off and bring heartbeat online, httpd should start and be available.  You can confirm by running either command below.

`ifconfig` or `service heartbeat status`

e.g. output

```
service heartbeat status
heartbeat OK [pid 3207 et al] is running on <node_name>, in this case web01
web01>ifconfig
eth0:0    ----------------------------------------------  
          inet addr:192.168.193.60  Bcast:192.168.193.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Let me know if that fixed it for you.